# Activating Lightbox on HTML elements with the has-lightbox class

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm in the process of trying to do "object oriented thinking", as to improve my code skill.

I've the following method that creates a lightbox for every item with the class `.has-lightbox`. Is this something that would benefit from being a class? A LightboxCollection class for example? That has an array Lightbox?

```
import * as basicLightbox from 'basiclightbox';

var lightboxableImages = document.getElementsByClassName("has-lightbox");
for (let image of lightboxableImages) {
    image.addEventListener('click', openLightbox);
}

function openLightbox(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const src = target.dataset['lightbox-src'] ? target.dataset['lightbox-src'] : target.src;

    if (!src) {
        return false;
    }

    const instance = basicLightbox.create(`<img src="${src}">`);
    instance.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Objects not classes

In JavaScript there are no classes only Objects. The token `class` is just an alternative syntax (often referred to as syntactical sugar) for defining an Object.

### Many ways to create objects

The following shows two very similar objects defined using class syntax and standard syntax

```
class Foo {
   constructor() { this.bar = "A" }
   poo() {}
}

function Foo() { this.bar = "B" }
Foo.prototype = { poo() {} }
```

You can also define the object as...

```
function Foo() {
   this.bar = "C";
   this.poo = function(){};
}
```

or...

```
const Foo = {
    bar: "D",
    poo() {},
};
```

or...

```
const Foo = () => ({
    bar: "D",
    poo() {},
});
```

...and there are many more ways to define an object.

### Which to use

Which you use is very dependent on how you use the object.

- Is there more than one instance?
- What is the life time of an instance?
- Do you need to extend the object? (polymorphic)
- What level of encapsulation is required?
- Do you need an inheritance model?
- How do you wish to instantiate the object?
- What is the legacy support requirement?

To know the language you must be proficient in all its forms, and know what is the appropriate code to use.

### Questions

> Is this something that would benefit from being a class?

No as there are no classes in JavaScript.

> A `LightboxCollection` class for example? That has an array `Lightbox`?

You can create a collection from an `Array`. Assuming you are using only a single instance. It has all the functions that an array has plus what ever you want to add. Eg `add`

```
const LightboxCollection = (() => {
    return Object.assign([],{
         add(lightBox){ this.push(lightBox) },
    });
})();
```

Or encapsulate the array, so you can maintain the array state (vet items and expose only functions that you need)

```
const LightboxCollection = (() => {
    const items = [];
    return Object.freeze({
         add(lightBox) { lightBox instanceof LightBox && items.push(lightBox) },
         get length() { return items.length },
         set length(len) { items.length = len < items.length ? len : items.length },
         forEach: items.forEach.bind(items),
    });
})();
```